# Is there any way to run the composer install command on a route or controller?

Tags: laravel, quick-install-package

Is there any way to run the composer install command on a route or controller ?
Because i'm doing function install package when click button.
Thanks so much

Comment: In general, this introduces significant security challenges.

Comment: Yea It's possible. You can find your solution here https://fivea.pk/run-composer-commands-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this then you can setup your commands https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Im sorry for misunderstand, you can call your command by execute it from .sh file. Follow these step: [Run .sh file using exec Laravel PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374495/run-sh-file-using-exec-laravel-php?answertab=active#tab-top)